# PHP Image upload, set name as the image HTML Input name=""

Tags: php, html, arrays, file-rename

I would like to set the name of the image to be the same as the name="" field.

This is where I set the name of the image when its been uploaded, where the XXXX is, this is where I want to output the name 'front' that is stored in name="front" in the HTML FILE Input:

```
$custom_name = "[" . "CANON" . "]_" . "XXXXXX";
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" class="admin_image_form" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="input-tag">Front</div>
    <label class="upload-button">
        <input type="file" name="front">
        Choose Image
    </label><br>
</form>
```

I have tried replacing the `XXXX` with '`$_FILES['front']['name']`' however this just sets the uploaded file name to '`CANON_.png`' followed by the original name of the image, I want it to be '`CANON_front.png`' with '`front`' coming from the `name="front"` in html

Thanks for any help.

Comment: just concatenate it, just not "that" way.

Comment: I need the value from the actual name="" itself not just concatenating it

Comment: `$file = $_FILES['front']['name'];
$new_name = "CANON" . "_" . $file;` if that's what you're looking to get.

Comment: Perfect, Thankyou very much  :)

Comment: I'll post an answer then, welcome

Comment: I have to wait 2 mins, then ill mark as accepted answer

Comment: No worries; I know how "Stack rolls" ;-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply assign a variable to the FILES array's name and then tack on a concatenated underscore with the file name after it, that is preceded by "CANON".

```
$file = $_FILES['front']['name'];
$new_name = "CANON" . "_" . $file;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your form to this `input hidden="front"`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#new" ).hide();
});
</script>
    <form method="POST" class="admin_image_form" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="input-tag">Front</div>
        <label class="upload-button">
    <input id="new" style="color: white;" type="hidden" name="front" />
            <input type="file" name="file">
            Choose Image
        </label><br>
    </form>
```

```
<?php 
$custom_name = "[" . "CANON" . "]_" . "XXXXXX";
$_FILES['front']['name']
?>
```